# Kubernetes set Eviction Thresholds, system-reserved , kube-reserved

Tags: azure, kubernetes, acs

How to set the reserved resources without ssh the cluster (only with kubectl commands) in azure (acs-engine) ?

Answer (score 4):

Using [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) command-line tool to achieve your goal is not feasible, as it only sends commands to api-server and retrieves results without any possibility to change global cluster configuration. The above parameters belong to [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) configuration. `Kubelet` is the node agent in a Kubernetes cluster and is responsible for the Pod lifecycle management on each local Node. Representing itself as a service, `kubelet` interacts with the `etcd` store in order to read configuration details or write new values.

You can apply specific flags when you implement `kubelet` service on your node or consider to change the configuration on a [live cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/) by changing parameters accordingly on the target Node.

There is a separate discussion about customization of `kubelet` parameters on `AKS` described [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/323).